# Linode Shodowsocks New Deploy ERROR: Bind: Address Already In Use

Tags: proxy, linode

root@00-00-00-00:~# ss-server -c /etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json -v
2021-11-02 19:54:26 INFO: initializing ciphers? aes-256-gcm
2021-11-02 19:54:26 INFO: tcp server listening at xx.xx.xx.xx:xx00
2021-11-02 19:54:26 ERROR: bind: Address already in use
2021-11-02 19:54:26 ERROR: failed to bind address

This is a brand new deployment from the marketplace.
How do I clear this error?
Thanks!

Comment: There may already be something binding to that socket, elsewhere on the system.  However, you probably need to provide more details about your system (including what else might be running) in order to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was brand new deployment so I did understand the error.

It appears that it was already running, thus trying to run it again resulted in that error message.

ss -plunt | grep "ss-server"

That is a good command to run to see if it is working.

Comment: I learned how to run the 'top' command.  I found that the service was already running.